# What does "Volt = 71R , Black = OOA" mean in terms of color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I am currently working on images that have a neon color.

The client has given me this color information :

Volt = 71R , Black = OOA

Can anyone please explain what this information means?

Thankyou for your time!

A

Comment: Seems like the best person to ask would be the client ;)

Comment: is the neon a red? 71R might be rgb(71,0,0), black might be rgb(0,0,10) (hex(#00000A)). Asking the client helps.

Comment: I agree with @JohnB, if they are giving you volt readings and you are working on neons..  maybe it is for the neon tube.

Answer (score 5):

I work for the company that appears to be your client. These are internal color codes that do not correspond to any color system, RGB, CMYK, etc. As has been suggested, you should ask for the corresponding color system info.

71R Volt is a standard fluorescent yellow.
00A Black is standard black.

You can google for most of these colors (just put in the name of the company and the color name, no color code) and find pictures that will be sufficient.